# How can I mirror tikzpicture (LTR to RTL) at once

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a big `tikz` picture which is very hard to mirror manually. The manually solution is to changing the `x-axis` coordinations negative and all `west` to `east` and etc.

But is very hard to do.   So I need to a faster solution than making coordinations negative.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Arial}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
                    \draw (-1,16.5) node[circle,minimum height=0.05cm,minimum width=0.05cm,draw,very thick,fill=black,label=left:$1951$] (HT) {};
                    \draw (-1,14.5) node[fill=black,circle,minimum height=0.1cm,minimum width=0.1cm,draw,very thick,label=left:$1958$] (DT) {};
                    \draw (-1,12.5) node[fill=black,circle,minimum height=0.1cm,minimum width=0.1cm,draw,very thick,label=left:$1996$] (BST) {};
                    \draw (-1,10.5) node[fill=black,circle,minimum height=0.1cm,minimum width=0.1cm,draw,very thick,label=left:$2008$] (SDT) {};
                    \draw (-1,8.5) node[fill=black,circle,minimum height=0.1cm,minimum width=0.1cm,draw,very thick,label=left:$2010$] (CQT) {};
                    \draw (-1,6.5) node[fill=black,circle,minimum height=0.1cm,minimum width=0.1cm,draw,very thick,label=left:$2013$] (PAT) {};
                    \draw (-1,4.5) node[fill=black,circle,minimum height=0.1cm,minimum width=0.1cm,draw,very thick,label=left:$2014$] (RST) {};
                    \draw (-1,2.5) node[fill=black,circle,minimum height=0.1cm,minimum width=0.1cm,draw,very thick,label=left:$2014$] (AHT) {};
                    \draw[very thick] (HT.south) |- (AHT.north);

                    \draw (1,16.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw,very thick,] (H) { \rl{هتلینگ ($\mathrm{H}$)}};
                    \draw (5.5,16.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,circle] (DH) {\rl{ناوردای تبدیلات خطی}};
                    \draw (10,16.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,very thick,] (BadH)
                    { \rl{ناکارا در شرایط بُعد بالا}};
                    \draw (1,14.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw,very thick] (D) {\rl{دمپستر ($\mathbf{D}$)}};
                    \draw (5.5,14.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,circle] (DD) 
                    {\rl{کارا در مسائل بُعد بالا}};
                    \draw (10,14.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,very thick,] (BadD)
                    { \rl{پیچیدگی محاسبه‌ی درجه آزادی مدل}};
                    \draw (1,12.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (BS) {\rl{بای و ساراناداسا (\lr{BS})}};
                    \draw (5.5,12.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,circle] (BSD) 
                    {\rl{توان مشابه \lr{D} و دقت بیشتر}};
                    \draw (10,12.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,very thick,] (BadBS)
                    { \rl{وردای تبدیلات مقیاسی}};
                    \draw (1,10.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (SD) {\rl{سریواستا و دو (\lr{SD})}};
                    \draw (5.5,10.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,circle] (SDD) 
                    {\rl{ناوردای تبدیلات مقیاسی}};
                    \draw (10,10.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,very thick,] (BadSD)
                    { \rl{فرض $\frac{p}{n} \rightarrow c$}};
                    \draw (1,8.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (CQ) {\rl{چن و کین (\lr{CQ})}};
                    \draw (5.5,8.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,circle] (CQD) 
                    {\rl{بهبود آزمون \lr{BS}}};
                    \draw (10,8.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,very thick,] (BadCQ)
                    { \rl{وردای تبدیلات مقیاسی}};
                    \draw (1,6.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (PA) {\rl{پارک و آیالا (\lr{PA})}};
                    \draw (5.5,6.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,circle] (PAD) 
                    {\rl{فرض شرط $\frac{p}{n} \rightarrow \infty$}};
                    \draw (10,6.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,very thick,] (BadPA)
                    { \rl{وردای تبدیلات مقیاسی}};
                    \draw (1,4.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (RS) {\rl{ثولین (\lr{RS})}};
                    \draw (5.5,4.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,circle] (RSD) 
                    {\rl{تشخیص‌دهنده‌ی بُعدهای عامل انحراف}};
                    \draw (10,4.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,very thick,] (BadRS)
                    { \rl{وردای تبدیلات مکان و مقیاس}};
                    \draw (10,3.9) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,very thick,] (BadRS2)
                    { \rl{و فرض نرمال بودن داده‌ها}};
                    \draw (1,2.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (AH) {\rl{احمد (\lr{AH})}};
                    \draw (5.5,2.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,circle] (AHD)
                    {\rl{در داده‌های همبسته پرتوان‌تر از $\texttt{RS}$}};
                    \draw (10,2.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,very thick,] (BadAH)
                    { \rl{فرض نرمال‌بودن داده‌ها}};
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (H.south) |- (D.north);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (H.east) |- (DH.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (D.east) |- (DD.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (DD.east) |- (BadD.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (DH.east) |- (BadH.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick] (D.south) |- (BS.north);       
                    \draw[bend left,->,very thick] (BS.east) to node [auto] {}
                    (CQ.east);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (BS.east) |- (BSD.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (BSD.east) |- (BadBS.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (SD.east) |- (SDD.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (SDD.east) |- (BadSD.west);
                    \draw[bend left,->,very thick] (SD.east) to node [auto] {}
                    (PA.east);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (CQ.east) |- (CQD.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (CQD.east) |- (BadCQ.west);
                    \draw[dashed,-<,very thick] (RS.south) |- (AH.north);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (PA.east) |- (PAD.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (PAD.east) |- (BadPA.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (RS.east) |- (RSD.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (RSD.east) |- (BadRS.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (AH.east) |- (AHD.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (AHD.east) |- (BadAH.west);
                    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: add the option [xscale=-1]... (Not tested but have to work)

Comment: If you also want to mirror the text, put the tikz picture into a `\reflectbox`.

Comment: there is not other way ...

Comment: @koleygr Thanks. it works but collapse the automatic connections between nodes unfortunately.

Comment: @marmot Thanks your solution works also. but also mirror the texts!!

Comment: @SirSaleh, sorry, but without see any part of the code for these connections I can't help you...

Comment: @koleygr I added `MWE`. it need `Arial` font for `persian` language which is pre-installed on most of Operating systems.

Comment: I think that if you replace "left:$" with "right:$" in all the document you will get what you want... But haven't test also... I just found that this is the only part that is x-invertion-sensitive ... For anything else like custom placed nodes I am afraid you really have to change manually.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote. Of course, you could put all texts in additional `\reflectbox`es. Perhaps it is possible to replace all texts with an intelligent search & replace for that. (I can't edit your code because the fonts do not work with my editor).

Comment: ... probably you just need a redefinition of `\rl` and `\rl`.... and of curse `\reflectbox` for the whole thin.

Comment: @koleygr Good solution, I used replace and find of my editor :) thanks anyway for your trying.

Comment: If you want to try marmot's solution too, just use reflectbox on your picture and just before the`\begin{tikzpicture}` (on the old code) command add  1) `\let\oldrl\rl` 2) `let\oldlr\lr` 3) `\def\rl\oldrl` 4) `\def\lr\oldrl` ... If it works too, I think is more elegant solution for your request... (Just made clear his own thought)

Comment: @koleygr I test it! Unfortunately it not worked. Maybe It's correct solution but while using `xepersian` package and `Right to left` languages it not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *should* do the trick for you. I cannot check because some Parsi things are missing on my installation. If it does not work, I'll be happy to remove the post.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Arial}
\begin{document}
Reflected picture:\\
\newcommand{\NewRL}[1]{\reflectbox{\rl{#1}}}
\newcommand{\NewLR}[1]{\reflectbox{\lr{#1}}}
\reflectbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
                   \draw (-1,16.5) node[circle,minimum height=0.05cm,minimum width=0.05cm,draw,very thick,fill=black,label=left:{\reflectbox{1951}}] (HT) {};
                    \draw (-1,14.5) node[fill=black,circle,minimum height=0.1cm,minimum width=0.1cm,draw,very thick,label=left:{\reflectbox{1958}}] (DT) {};
                    \draw (-1,12.5) node[fill=black,circle,minimum height=0.1cm,minimum width=0.1cm,draw,very thick,label=left:{\reflectbox{1996}}] (BST) {};
                    \draw (-1,10.5) node[fill=black,circle,minimum height=0.1cm,minimum width=0.1cm,draw,very thick,label=left:{\reflectbox{2008}}] (SDT) {};
                    \draw (-1,8.5) node[fill=black,circle,minimum height=0.1cm,minimum width=0.1cm,draw,very thick,label=left:{\reflectbox{2010}}] (CQT) {};
                    \draw (-1,6.5) node[fill=black,circle,minimum height=0.1cm,minimum width=0.1cm,draw,very thick,label=left:{\reflectbox{2013}}] (PAT) {};
                    \draw (-1,4.5) node[fill=black,circle,minimum height=0.1cm,minimum width=0.1cm,draw,very thick,label=left:{\reflectbox{2014}}] (RST) {};
                    \draw (-1,2.5) node[fill=black,circle,minimum height=0.1cm,minimum width=0.1cm,draw,very thick,label=left:{\reflectbox{2014}}] (AHT) {};
                    \draw[very thick] (HT.south) |- (AHT.north);

                    \draw (1,16.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw,very thick,] (H) { \NewRL{هتلینگ ($\mathrm{H}$)}};
                    \draw (5.5,16.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,circle] (DH) {\NewRL{ناوردای تبدیلات خطی}};
                    \draw (10,16.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,very thick,] (BadH)
                    { \NewRL{ناکارا در شرایط بُعد بالا}};
                    \draw (1,14.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw,very thick] (D) {\NewRL{دمپستر ($\mathbf{D}$)}};
                    \draw (5.5,14.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,circle] (DD) 
                    {\NewRL{کارا در مسائل بُعد بالا}};
                    \draw (10,14.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,very thick,] (BadD)
                    { \NewRL{پیچیدگی محاسبه‌ی درجه آزادی مدل}};
                    \draw (1,12.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (BS) {\NewRL{بای و ساراناداسا (\NewLR{BS})}};
                    \draw (5.5,12.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,circle] (BSD) 
                    {\NewRL{توان مشابه \NewLR{D} و دقت بیشتر}};
                    \draw (10,12.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,very thick,] (BadBS)
                    { \NewRL{وردای تبدیلات مقیاسی}};
                    \draw (1,10.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (SD) {\NewRL{سریواستا و دو (\NewLR{SD})}};
                    \draw (5.5,10.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,circle] (SDD) 
                    {\NewRL{ناوردای تبدیلات مقیاسی}};
                    \draw (10,10.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,very thick,] (BadSD)
                    { \NewRL{فرض $\frac{p}{n} \rightarrow c$}};
                    \draw (1,8.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (CQ) {\NewRL{چن و کین (\NewLR{CQ})}};
                    \draw (5.5,8.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,circle] (CQD) 
                    {\NewRL{بهبود آزمون \NewLR{BS}}};
                    \draw (10,8.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,very thick,] (BadCQ)
                    { \NewRL{وردای تبدیلات مقیاسی}};
                    \draw (1,6.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (PA) {\NewRL{پارک و آیالا (\NewLR{PA})}};
                    \draw (5.5,6.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,circle] (PAD) 
                    {\NewRL{فرض شرط $\frac{p}{n} \rightarrow \infty$}};
                    \draw (10,6.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,very thick,] (BadPA)
                    { \NewRL{وردای تبدیلات مقیاسی}};
                    \draw (1,4.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (RS) {\NewRL{ثولین (\NewLR{RS})}};
                    \draw (5.5,4.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,circle] (RSD) 
                    {\NewRL{تشخیص‌دهنده‌ی بُعدهای عامل انحراف}};
                    \draw (10,4.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,very thick,] (BadRS)
                    { \NewRL{وردای تبدیلات مکان و مقیاس}};
                    \draw (10,3.9) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,very thick,] (BadRS2)
                    { \NewRL{و فرض نرمال بودن داده‌ها}};
                    \draw (1,2.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (AH) {\NewRL{احمد (\NewLR{AH})}};
                    \draw (5.5,2.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,circle] (AHD)
                    {\NewRL{در داده‌های همبسته پرتوان‌تر از $\texttt{RS}$}};
                    \draw (10,2.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,very thick,] (BadAH)
                    { \NewRL{فرض نرمال‌بودن داده‌ها}};
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (H.south) |- (D.north);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (H.east) |- (DH.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (D.east) |- (DD.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (DD.east) |- (BadD.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (DH.east) |- (BadH.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick] (D.south) |- (BS.north);       
                    \draw[bend left,->,very thick] (BS.east) to node [auto] {}
                    (CQ.east);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (BS.east) |- (BSD.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (BSD.east) |- (BadBS.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (SD.east) |- (SDD.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (SDD.east) |- (BadSD.west);
                    \draw[bend left,->,very thick] (SD.east) to node [auto] {}
                    (PA.east);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (CQ.east) |- (CQD.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (CQD.east) |- (BadCQ.west);
                    \draw[dashed,-<,very thick] (RS.south) |- (AH.north);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (PA.east) |- (PAD.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (PAD.east) |- (BadPA.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (RS.east) |- (RSD.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (RSD.east) |- (BadRS.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (AH.east) |- (AHD.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (AHD.east) |- (BadAH.west);
                    \end{tikzpicture}
}

Original picture:\\


\begin{tikzpicture}
                    \draw (-1,16.5) node[circle,minimum height=0.05cm,minimum width=0.05cm,draw,very thick,fill=black,label=left:$1951$] (HT) {};
                    \draw (-1,14.5) node[fill=black,circle,minimum height=0.1cm,minimum width=0.1cm,draw,very thick,label=left:$1958$] (DT) {};
                    \draw (-1,12.5) node[fill=black,circle,minimum height=0.1cm,minimum width=0.1cm,draw,very thick,label=left:$1996$] (BST) {};
                    \draw (-1,10.5) node[fill=black,circle,minimum height=0.1cm,minimum width=0.1cm,draw,very thick,label=left:$2008$] (SDT) {};
                    \draw (-1,8.5) node[fill=black,circle,minimum height=0.1cm,minimum width=0.1cm,draw,very thick,label=left:$2010$] (CQT) {};
                    \draw (-1,6.5) node[fill=black,circle,minimum height=0.1cm,minimum width=0.1cm,draw,very thick,label=left:$2013$] (PAT) {};
                    \draw (-1,4.5) node[fill=black,circle,minimum height=0.1cm,minimum width=0.1cm,draw,very thick,label=left:$2014$] (RST) {};
                    \draw (-1,2.5) node[fill=black,circle,minimum height=0.1cm,minimum width=0.1cm,draw,very thick,label=left:$2014$] (AHT) {};
                    \draw[very thick] (HT.south) |- (AHT.north);

                    \draw (1,16.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw,very thick,] (H) { \rl{هتلینگ ($\mathrm{H}$)}};
                    \draw (5.5,16.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,circle] (DH) {\rl{ناوردای تبدیلات خطی}};
                    \draw (10,16.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,very thick,] (BadH)
                    { \rl{ناکارا در شرایط بُعد بالا}};
                    \draw (1,14.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw,very thick] (D) {\rl{دمپستر ($\mathbf{D}$)}};
                    \draw (5.5,14.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,circle] (DD) 
                    {\rl{کارا در مسائل بُعد بالا}};
                    \draw (10,14.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,very thick,] (BadD)
                    { \rl{پیچیدگی محاسبه‌ی درجه آزادی مدل}};
                    \draw (1,12.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (BS) {\rl{بای و ساراناداسا (\lr{BS})}};
                    \draw (5.5,12.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,circle] (BSD) 
                    {\rl{توان مشابه \lr{D} و دقت بیشتر}};
                    \draw (10,12.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,very thick,] (BadBS)
                    { \rl{وردای تبدیلات مقیاسی}};
                    \draw (1,10.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (SD) {\rl{سریواستا و دو (\lr{SD})}};
                    \draw (5.5,10.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,circle] (SDD) 
                    {\rl{ناوردای تبدیلات مقیاسی}};
                    \draw (10,10.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,very thick,] (BadSD)
                    { \rl{فرض $\frac{p}{n} \rightarrow c$}};
                    \draw (1,8.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (CQ) {\rl{چن و کین (\lr{CQ})}};
                    \draw (5.5,8.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,circle] (CQD) 
                    {\rl{بهبود آزمون \lr{BS}}};
                    \draw (10,8.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,very thick,] (BadCQ)
                    { \rl{وردای تبدیلات مقیاسی}};
                    \draw (1,6.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (PA) {\rl{پارک و آیالا (\lr{PA})}};
                    \draw (5.5,6.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,circle] (PAD) 
                    {\rl{فرض شرط $\frac{p}{n} \rightarrow \infty$}};
                    \draw (10,6.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,very thick,] (BadPA)
                    { \rl{وردای تبدیلات مقیاسی}};
                    \draw (1,4.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (RS) {\rl{ثولین (\lr{RS})}};
                    \draw (5.5,4.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,circle] (RSD) 
                    {\rl{تشخیص‌دهنده‌ی بُعدهای عامل انحراف}};
                    \draw (10,4.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,very thick,] (BadRS)
                    { \rl{وردای تبدیلات مکان و مقیاس}};
                    \draw (10,3.9) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,very thick,] (BadRS2)
                    { \rl{و فرض نرمال بودن داده‌ها}};
                    \draw (1,2.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (AH) {\rl{احمد (\lr{AH})}};
                    \draw (5.5,2.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,circle] (AHD)
                    {\rl{در داده‌های همبسته پرتوان‌تر از $\texttt{RS}$}};
                    \draw (10,2.5) node[minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm,very thick,] (BadAH)
                    { \rl{فرض نرمال‌بودن داده‌ها}};
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (H.south) |- (D.north);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (H.east) |- (DH.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (D.east) |- (DD.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (DD.east) |- (BadD.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (DH.east) |- (BadH.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick] (D.south) |- (BS.north);       
                    \draw[bend left,->,very thick] (BS.east) to node [auto] {}
                    (CQ.east);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (BS.east) |- (BSD.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (BSD.east) |- (BadBS.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (SD.east) |- (SDD.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (SDD.east) |- (BadSD.west);
                    \draw[bend left,->,very thick] (SD.east) to node [auto] {}
                    (PA.east);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (CQ.east) |- (CQD.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (CQD.east) |- (BadCQ.west);
                    \draw[dashed,-<,very thick] (RS.south) |- (AH.north);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (PA.east) |- (PAD.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (PAD.east) |- (BadPA.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (RS.east) |- (RSD.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (RSD.east) |- (BadRS.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (AH.east) |- (AHD.west);
                    \draw[-<,very thick,dashed] (AHD.east) |- (BadAH.west);
                    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It working like a charm :)) thanks man. looks like I've done it badly before.

Answer (score 3):

To mirror a `tikzpicture`, you can use the options

1. `[xscale=-1]` for *horizontal* mirroring
2. `[yscale=-1]` for *vertical* mirroring 
   or
3. `[scale=-1]` for *both axes* mirroring

In your case, you had some nodes with the option `[left]`... In this way the best solution was just to use your editor to replace "`left:$`" by "`right:$`" because I suppose that this exact phrase appears only at the specific places and not on other that the replacement would create problems...

Comment: You were right koleygr. marmont solution also works perfectly. Unfortunately I can't accept both of you solutions. But thank you both :)

Comment: The answer is not self-contained. It does not draw anything